# GSM network parameters in Android?

Tags: android, mobile, gsm

Is it possible to access to gsm network parameters like bcch tch and sdcch channels and neighbors and signal level and ,,,?  I mean how can we access to these codes in android programming?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You have to type the code `*#*#197328640#*#*` into your mobile. That is the service menu. There is a lot of information about GSM and UMTS.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. But how can we use these codes in android programming?

Comment: @xxx Is that general for Android phones? According to this, it seems to work only for Samsung phones http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2147211